# Ubuntu and Windows Server 2008 NFS

Tags: 10.10, windows, nfs, users

**Background**

I am trying to configure NFS on my Windows Server 2008 with UNIX Extensions to be able to connect to Ubuntu. However in 2008 you need AD to activate User Profile Mappings. Windows can however connect to a Identity Manager Service to retrieve this information from another machine. The reason for not running AD is that the server and setup is on a home network, and therefore AD is completely unnecessary.

**The Question**

How and can I configure my Ubuntu machine to provide a User Profile Mapping service, and what/how would I go about setting it up on my Ubuntu machine? I need to be able to map my Windows Users to my Linux users without require AD.

The problem with using OpenLDAP is that it doesn't support Server 2008 and also I am not sharing anything **from** Ubuntu. Also NFS can see the shares on the Server however can't connect to them in anyway.

**Current Setup**

I am running Ubuntu 10.10 without any GUI. It is a headless installation mainly used to run service type software and to do some network monitoring. It does not have any shares on the box, however connects to shares on the Windows Server 2008 machine using CIFS and FSTAB mounts. However I would like to switch to NFS because symlinks won't work when running RSYNC to backup the Ubuntu box for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking to set up a Windows domain controller on Ubuntu, which you can do with a combo of OpenLDAP and Samba.

Here's a very thorough guide:
http://download.gna.org/smbldap-tools/docs/samba-ldap-howto/

Comment: Thanks. This does answer my question however the problem with this particular solution is it does not work with Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is *User Profile Mappings* but I can suggest this new NFS 4.1 driver to provide NFS shares on Windows:

http://www.citi.umich.edu/projects/nfsv4/windows/readme.html

Comment: Not what I am looking for. I have NFS working, my problem is I need to be able to map the user accounts on the Ubuntu box with my users on my Windows box, therefore I need the built in User Profile Mappings to work. Also the Windows Box is the NFS server, not the other way around.